# PyQt5 - How to make a push button always has true value when click down and false value when it has up

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyqt5

Im just try to use PyQt5 for my robot GUI. im little bit confuse how to use momentary push button which should giving true value when it pressed down and false value when it unpressed. fyi im using python for this.

im already try to use "setCheckable" to detecting its state, but it make the button toggled (not momentary). is there any other methode that i can implement?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the `clicked` signal, aren't you?

Comment: So you want the button to emit True when you press it down and false when it comes back up, but you still want the button to come back up immediately after pressing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`clicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) signal is always emitted *after* the mouse button is released *in* the button rectangle. That's the common convention for a "click event" of buttons in almost any reasonable UI toolkit.

If you want to know when the button is pressed or released, then you can connect to the [`pressed`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#pressed) and [`released`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#released) signals.

Be aware, though, that the common convention above also considers that if the user *leaves* the button while the mouse button is still pressed, the button becomes "unpressed" as well, and becomes pressed again if the mouse goes back inside its geometry while the same mouse button is still pressed. This means that if you connect to those signals and the user "leaves" the button with the mouse button still pressed and gets back to it, you might get inconsistent results depending on your needs.

If you are interested in the basic "just when mouse button was pressed" and "mouse button released at last" state, no matter if the user released the mouse button outside of the widget, then the only option is to override the mouse button handlers and use a custom signal:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class IgnoreClickPosButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    pressedState = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bool)
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.pressedState.emit(True)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.pressedState.emit(False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    btn = IgnoreClickPosButton()
    btn.pressedState.connect(lambda p: print('pressed', p))
    btn.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```